# Error Xorg - Matrox M9138 Graphics card - drivers

Tags: drivers, xorg, matrox

Below is what I have done so far to download the drivers for a Matrox M9138 graphics card. Have run into an error to update XOrg to 1.15.  I believe the present update listed is a 1.20.4.

I am thinking need to revert to a previous version of Xorg 1.15 or is there another way to maybe force the driver software to take the 1.20.4? If I revert to a previous version 1.15.  What is the procedure to accomplish and what are the ramifications?

System Configuration

- Device:        rob-MS-7998
- Operating system:  Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
- Memory:            62.9 GiB
- Processor:     Intel Xeon(R) CPU E3-1240 v5 @ 3.50GHz x 8
- Graphics:      1024x768   llvmpipe (LLVM 8.0,256 bits)  The X.Org Foundation
- Graphics card:     Matrox M9138 card
- GNOME:         3.28.2
- OS type:       64-bit
- Disk:          982.8 GB
- Motherboard:       1.0/C236A WORKSTATION (MS-7998) (MSI)

Initial errors that I got:

```
Creating directory cd /home/rob/m9xdriver-x86_64-1.4.3-80847-20140908-build_98
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing Matrox M9X Driver./m9xdriver-x86_64-1.4.3-80847-20140908-build_98.run: 338: cd: can't cd to cd /home/rob/m9xdriver-x86_64-1.4.3-80847-20140908-build_98
........................................................................................................................................................................
./m9xdriver-x86_64-1.4.3-80847-20140908-build_98.run: 363: cd: can't cd to cd /home/rob/m9xdriver-x86_64-1.4.3-80847-20140908-build_98


========================================
   Matrox Linux Driver Install Script   
========================================

-----------------------------------------------------------
 ERROR: You must be logged in as Root to run this program.
-----------------------------------------------------------

The program returned an error code (1)
```

When tried with `sudo` privileges:

```
$ sudo sh m9xdriver-x86_64-1.4.3-80847-20140908-build_98.run
Please, enter the directory to extract the files [/home/rob/] /home/rob/
Creating directory /home/rob//m9xdriver-x86_64-1.4.3-80847-20140908-build_98
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing Matrox M9X Driver........................................................................................................................................................................


========================================
   Matrox Linux Driver Install Script   
========================================

 **ERROR: Xorg 6.9, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 7.5 or xserver 1.9, 1.10, 1.11, 1.12, 1.13, 1.14 or 1.15 not found. Please update Xorg.**

The program returned an error code (1)
```

Output of `apt-cache show xserver-xorg | grep Version`:

```
Version: 1:7.7+19ubuntu7.1
Version: 1:7.7+19ubuntu7
```

X version:

```
$ sudo X -version
X.Org X Server 1.20.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-148-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux rob-MS-7998 5.0.0-27-generic #28~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 22 03:00:32 UTC 2019 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-27-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
Build Date: 02 May 2019  08:06:54AM
xorg-server-hwe-18.04 2:1.20.4-1ubuntu3~18.04.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
```

Output of `lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12`:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. M91XX [102b:0540] (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. M9138 LP PCIe x16 [102b:2241]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at dfe20000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

02:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller [1b21:1242] (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller [1462:7998]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at dfd00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Comment: Please don't add *solved* and what you find in the question. Instead use the "Answer your question" button below. For now I have redacted the answer from question and posted a Community Wiki answer. But if you wish to post it on your own, please ping me using @Kulfy in the comments. I'll delete my answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

As per [Revision #2](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1173322/2) of the question:

> Answer from Matrox via email:
>
> As it stands, technical support for use of M-series on Linux is essentially limited to the information found in the "readme" with the driver download.
>
> As seen in that ["readme" document](ftp://ftp.matrox.com/pub/mga/archive/linux/2015/1.4.3/README143.txt) the last released driver for M-series (including M9138) supports Ubuntu 14.04 and X Server version 1.15. Use of Ubuntu 18.04 and X Server version is not supported, and the driver will not install.
>
> Our recommendation would be to use a version of Ubuntu that is supported.